# store aggregation result of a time-frame into Flink's state backend

Tags: apache-flink

I'm new to Apache Flink (1 day :) ), and have seen in few guides it save state.
[by documentation, you can use:](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/state_backends.html)

- memoryStateBacked
- FsStateBackend
- RocksDBStateBackend

nevertheless I couldn't find a sample code of reading/writing to this state backend.

Does that mean that it is for Flink's internal usage, or I can use as well?

meaning: can I store last day aggregations, reset Flink, and then read the cache again? (like you would do with Redis for example)

Comment: Did you ever found an answer to this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Flink's state backends are used for storing the current state of your operator.

There are examples and detailed explanation available [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/state.html) if you haven't seen already.

Essentially, the state is defined in the `public void open(Configuration config)` function

and then in the `flatMap` function you can access the state by calling `mystate.value()` and can also be updated by using `mystate.update(newvalue)`

Currently this is what you can do with states, but there is a new feature called `QueryableState` which is in progress [FLINK-3779](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-3779), which enables you to query the Flink's state outside Flink.

PS : I am not aware of how Redis handles state

Comment: so there isnt a way to sae aggregation result? for example sum of last 10 minutes? i didnt find code sample for that. (the link you've added gives 404)